# remote: Permission Denied Asus Zenfone 2

Tags: fastboot, twrp

I recently (dumbly) removed my internal through TWRP on my Asus Zenfone 2 whilst trying to flash SuperZen from xda. So now I'm attempting to go back to stock, and I've tried doing a factory reset with the stock recovery, but with no luck. I'm currently trying to flash `boot.img`, `recovery.img`, `droidboot.img` and `system.img` via `fastboot` on Linux and Windows, but I get:

```
$ fastboot flash system system.img

target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
erasing 'system'...
FAILED (remote: Permission denied)
finished. total time: 0.136s
```

for each one. This is when trying to flash using version WW_2.19.40.22. The interesting thing is, is that when I flash `twrp.img` or `recovery.img`(stock) it still gives me that same error, but when I boot into recovery, I have either TWRP or stock recovery, which shows that it *did* work. Sadly, this is not the case with system, so if I reboot into the system, it does not work properly and hangs on the "Powered by Android" splash screen.

**EDIT:**
just tried using `fastboot update -w Zip_Name.zip` and it gives me:

```
archive does not contain 'android-info.txt'
archive does not contain 'android-product.txt'
error: update package has no android-info.txt or android-product.txt
```

**EDIT 2:**
booted into TWRP and used "Install" to try and flash the .zip I put on the SD card, I got the logs copied to the SD, and here is the relevant section:

```
minzip: Missed a central dir sig (at 0)
E:Zip file is corrupt!
MtpServer::run fd: 13
E:request read returned -1, errno: 5, exiting MtpServer::run loop
Error flashing zip '/external_sd/UL-Z00A-JP-2.19.40.21-user.zip'
Updating partition details...
I:Data backup size is 0MB, free: 55424MB.
...done
```

Basically, it gave me `E:Zip file is corrupt!` and ended up with "Failed".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138175/discussion-on-question-by-nixpower-remote-permission-denied-asus-zenfone-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve you problem execute the following :

1. Boot your Phone into TWRP Recovery.
2. Plug your phone to PC and make sure it is recognized by `adb` you can run `adb devices` command to check.
3. on you Phone TWRP go to `wipe > advanced wipe`  check `data ,cache and system` then swipe the swipe zone in the bottom
4. Now go back to the home of TWRP and navigate to `Advanced >> ADB sideload` swipe where it is written **Swipe to Start Sideload**
5. go to you PC and fire up a terminal or a cmd (depend on your operating system) and type this command `adb sideload path/to/you_firmaware.zip`
6. Your phone will start flashing the zip wait until it's done and then reboot your system.
7. the first boot may take awhile be patient.

Comment: Switched my SD card and I found out the root of the problem was the SD card reader, changed that and it no longer corrupted the zip. I'm back up and running now after flashing it through TWRP, but because this will most probably work to fix this issue as well, I will Accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that ,I answered with adb sideload method when I saw the log showing file system errors ,adb sideload will work even with no SD card

Comment: I was having some issues with sideload when I tried it prior to flashing with TWRP, so it may not work and you might need an SD card regardless. I know I'm not getting a device that doesn't have an SD card slot!

Comment: I have an HTC one ( no sdcard ) and I use adb sideload normally

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question here:
[Fastboot permission denied error in Asus Zenfone 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115516/fastboot-permission-denied-error-in-asus-zenfone-2/145904#145904)

Basically, you just need to remove all pin/pattern unlock on your phone first.