# Fastboot permission denied error in Asus Zenfone 2

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, twrp, asus-zenfone-2

I went into regular recovery mode to wipe cache and do factory reset to flash [clean Asus ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2/development/rom-2-19-40-18-rom-ze551-goodbye-t3144291) from XDA. I first went to wipe cache and it felt like it was taking way too long, so I turned off the phone  and tried to turn it back on, and now all I get is a dead Android.

I found this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2/help/how-to-upgrade-cn-version-to-ww-t3101556) on XDA to unbrick the phone but when I try the steps I am getting permission denied message while using fastboot. I cannot flash TWRP via fastboot either.

```
C:\Users\bdelc\Downloads\android\Fastboot>fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (11864 KB)...
OKAY [  0.628s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Permission denied)
finished. total time: 0.809s

C:\Users\bdelc\Downloads\android\Fastboot>fastboot flash boot boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot' (11850 KB)...
OKAY [  0.619s]
writing 'boot'...
FAILED (remote: Permission denied)
finished. total time: 0.804s

C:\Users\bdelc\Downloads\android\Fastboot>fastboot flash fastboot droidboot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'fastboot' (14800 KB)...
OKAY [  0.712s]
writing 'fastboot'...
FAILED (remote: Permission denied)
finished. total time: 0.888s

C:\Users\bdelc\Downloads\android\Fastboot>fastboot flash recovery twrp-2.8.7.1-fhd.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (14456 KB)...
OKAY [  0.844s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Permission denied)
finished. total time: 1.012s
```

Comment: Try to run Command prompt as administrator, find fastboot.exe and run it again. Sometimes it can cause Permission denied problem if cmd is not run as admin. Also you can check how fastboot see your device by executing - fastboot devices

Comment: hello, so apparently twrp flash worked even though it said permission denied. i am running cmd as admin and was still getting permission denied. tried it both ways. now i wonder if i can flash the zip file thru twrp to get back to stock.

Comment: I was able to flash TWRP with the flashboot method and tried to install the ZIP file from here - http://www.asus.com/us/Phones/ZenFon...Desk_Download/ (DL - http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Zen...40.22-user.zip) and it gives this error:

assert failed: getprop("ro.build.asus.sku") == "WW"
E:Error executing updater binary in zip '/external_sd/UL-Z00A-WW-2.19.40.22-user.zip'

Comment: you are flashing a eip with the wrong SKU version or region I don't know which SKU you have and I don't know if there is a diference between the two versions of the phones (I mean at the hardware level) or they are the same but with different bloat-ware ,you can grab the right version from here https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone_2_ZE551ML/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: if you do have the WW version of the phone then let me know to post a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok i was able to fix the problem. I was still able to load TWRP by flashboot, which I used to fix permissions and clear cache. The problem started because I went into normal recovery and went to wipe cache partition to load the SuperZen rom. The cache wipe seemed to take long, so I turned the phone off and back on and the only thing I was able to load was the fast boot. No recovery or normal mode worked, just ended up with a dead android. After fixing cache partition, I reloaded same 3 img files, kept getting permission denied error. Tried to get into recovery again and this time it worked! I used ADB sideload to flash the zip file above and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. The way to solve it is to remove all pin/pattern unlock. Simple!! But took a while to figure it out.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on fastboot.exe → Properties → Compatibility → tick "Run this program as Administrator" → Apply

Run your commands again, and on Administration prompt (...if it appears) click yes.

Good to go!

Comment: AndroidNotSoPowerUser already suggested that in the comments, and the OP stated he was already running fastboot as admin. That wouldn't make any difference anyway, as the "Permission denied" error comes from the phone, not the PC.